# Styling php generated link in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I have the following code in my wordpress loop to display sticky posts:

```
<div class="blogpost">
<?php // div class for styling sticky posts on main page. ?>
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_excerpt(); // Show summary of posts only. ?>
</div> <!-- end class sticky -->
</div> <!-- end class blogpost -->
```

I would like to style the h2 with CSS but I don't have access to it. When I take a look at the code in firebug it looks like this:

```
<div class="blogpost">
<div id="post-324" class="post-324 post type-post status-publish format-standard sticky hentry category-uncategorized" <h2="">

    <a href="http://mydomain.com/wordpress/?p=324">Headline of post </a>
    ...
</div>
</div>
```

Does anyone know what I have to change to get my headline h2 into the a? Thanks!

Comment: that second snippet has html syntax errors... the `<h2`> is going to be seen as an attribute of the post-324 div.

Comment: I know. The 2nd snippet is what Firebug gives me when I take a look at the code in Firefox. But I don't know why and how this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first block of code is missing a `>` after `<?php post_class(); ?>`. So, you should be able to style the `h2` once that's fixed.

If you want the `h2` inside the `a`, you could just put it inside:

`<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>`

Answer (score 0):

Loke at this part of your code

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>
```

Try this code:

```
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
```

All code:

```
<div class="blogpost">
<div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?= post_class(); ?>>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?= the_title(); ?></a></h2>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div> 
</div>
```